Bad wishes In Jannah
So it is said that once in jannah your mind will be purified and you won't wish for anything bad or inappropriate, and on the other side it is said that you can get whatever you want in Jannah , even bad things like alcohol will be purified in jannah and one can experience it in a way that is permissible and pure , also other bad things like pork and music they can also turn good , and as it is said that our minds will be purified does this mean we will not experience these somewhat inappropriate things from the world , not even in a form that is pure and permissible and harmless?? , can this turning of impure to pure and harmful to harmless not happen to all the BaD things from this world (in jannah)?? so one can experience it , for example if one loves boxing in this world and it is harmful in this world , but in jannah can he not make the wish for boxing , and experience it in a permissible harmless form , may be something like a video game(just an example) or any other way ,
(since Allah can do anything) ,
CAN ALL BAD THINGS NOT TURN GOOD IN JANNAH ??? Just curious

In Islam, Jannah (Paradise) is described  as a place of complete purity, joy, and peace, where desires and experiences are purified. This understanding is based on both Quranic verses and hadiths:

Purification of Hearts and Desires:

Allah mentions that people in Jannah will have pure hearts, free from any ill will or harmful desires.
In the Quran, Allah says:

“And We shall remove from their hearts any resentment—[so they will be like] brothers, on thrones facing each other.” (Quran 15:47)

This suggests that harmful or inappropriate desires from this world will naturally no longer exist in Jannah. Believers’ desires will align with the pure and beautiful nature of Paradise.

Transformation of Certain Forbidden Items:

Some things that are harmful or forbidden on earth will exist in a pure, permissible form in Jannah. For example, alcohol is prohibited in this world due to its intoxicating effects, but it is mentioned in a purified form in Jannah:

“A drink from a flowing stream, crystal-white, delicious to drink, causing neither headache nor intoxication.” (Quran 37:45-47)

This shows that Allah can make previously harmful or impure things into something pure and enjoyable in Jannah.

Possibility of Harmless Enjoyment:

As for experiences like boxing, which may be harmful in this life, scholars generally agree that if a person desires something similar, Allah can provide a form that is entirely harmless and enjoyable in Jannah. However, this is speculative, as Islamic sources do not describe every type of experience in detail. The focus is instead on Jannah being a place where all pure desires are fulfilled in ways that surpass human understanding:

“In it is what the souls desire and [what] delights the eyes, and you will abide therein eternally.” (Quran 43:71)


Absence of Harmful or Sinful Desires:

Based on the Quran and hadiths, scholars generally agree that the purification of minds and desires in Jannah means that desires for sinful or harmful things will not arise. Instead, people will have only pure, permissible desires. In this way, Jannah will remain a place of absolute peace, safety, and fulfillment.

TLDR
In short, while some previously forbidden things may exist in a purified form in Jannah (like alcohol), the purified nature of desires likely means that only pure and good things will be wished for and experienced. Allah assures believers that all wishes aligned with the pure nature of Jannah will be granted in ways that bring lasting happiness and peace.

Basically , as mentioned In the Quran , you can have anything you want in Jannah


There they will have whatever they desire, and with Us is ˹even˺ more. Quran 50:35
it is possible that Inappropriate things from this world can turn good in Jannah for example wine/alcohol is permissible and harmless in Jannah ,
This means bad and harmful things from this world can turn harmless and good in Jannah and can be experienced by the believer in a way that is pure and permissible ,
However, it is very obvious that Not ALL bad and inappropriate things from this world can be turned into pure form in Jannah
